# Can't run application in iOS 6.0 or 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am currently developing an application for iOS 6 and 7. I am using storyboards for the first time. When I use an iPhone or simulator with iOS 7 my app works fine.

However when I tried to run it on an iOS 6 or 6.1 it crashes with below error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
```

**Note**: My *Deployment Target* is 6.0, but my *Base SDK* is Latest(iOS 7.0).

- What settings should I check?
- Should I load an earlier SDK?
- Does storyboard has anything to do with this?

Comment: Please try to add an exception breakpoint and copy the code where the exception is thrown. You can add an exception breakpoint and the debugger should stop at the line throwing the exception: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: It's difficult to get idea here, can you post some code?

Comment: Show us some code, especially the part where it's complaining -> the initiWithString part.

Comment: If it helps this isn't complaining about `[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]` it's is most likely complaining about `[NSString initWithString:]`

Comment: Thanks @slecorne for the exception breakpoint:D Also it was as Popeye stated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

It clearly states about the exception that you are having an NSString object in your code somewhere which is getting the nil argument. So try to place breakpoint and use the debugger to check that where your NSString object is getting the nil argument and try to correct it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered such an issue when I updated to iOS 7 as well. The problem ended up being connected to the use of `UITextField`. Using the iOS 7 SDK and compiling for iOS 6, an empty text field returns `nil` instead of `@""`. As a result, if you do something like

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self.myTextField.text];
```

it will cause your code to explode as you are describing.